# Padding at the end of multiple lines in pure functions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have to use padEnd() in multiple lines in javascript.
Example:

```
pad('12ab\n121\n51', 5)
> '12ab \n121  \n51   '
```

My approach is:
          str.split(/\n/g).forEach((v) => {v.padEnd(5 , " ")});

Output is:
Undefined

Can someone give me a hint that what I am doing wrong and what else I need to do? (Please don't tell complete answers).

Comment: `padEnd` returns a new string, but you're throwing it away. If you want to use pure functions, never use `forEach`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead of forEach. At the end you can [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the result in order to get the string back.

The main difference between map and forEach is:

> - The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
> - The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

Your approach works if you change it a bit:

```
str = str.split(/\n/);
str.forEach((v, idx) => {str[idx] = v.padEnd(5, ".")});
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var str = '12ab\n121\n51';
str = str.split(/\n/).map((ele) => ele.padEnd(5, '.')).join('\n');

console.log('"' + str + '"');

// a diferent aproach

var str1 = '12ab\n121\n51';

str1 = str1.split(/\n/);
str1.forEach((v, idx) => {str1[idx] = v.padEnd(5, ".")});

console.log(str1);
```

Comment: Why I am not getting the desired output by using forEach()?

Comment: answer updated. While map works and elaborates each element, forEach loops on each array element. You can see in the updated snippet the difference.

Comment: +1 — I think the demonstration of `.map()` would be clearer if you used `"."` as the pad character, like you do in the `forEach` example. Also, you don't need the `/g` flag on the split regex; split already acts on the whole string: `"one\ntwo\nthree".split(/\n/).map(s => s.padEnd(7, '.')).join('\n')`

Comment: @StephenP You are right. Answer updated Thanks so much